# void Name(type name1,type name2, type name3[name1][name2] );

Tags: c, arrays, void

I don't know why my Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express doesn't support a code like this:

```
void ar(int n,int m, short ar[n][m]);
```

The thing that happens is that the letter n and m gets undercovered in red and it says:

```
//Error: a parameter is not allowed.
```

I'm coding in C and currently trying to learn about pointers and arrays.

Comment: Is that a declaration or a definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the passed array size to depend on a variable (moreover, passed in the same signature). It compiles in Clang, but it's not legal C89, it is C99 and AFAIK Microsoft VC does not fully support that.

Be careful: you are calling the function and its parameter by the same name and this might lead to funny, obscure errors. **Either rename the function or the last parameter.**

EDIT: try compiling this:

```
void ar(int n,int m, short ars[n][m])
{
}

int main()
{
    short a[1][2] = {{22,22}};
    ar(1,2,a);
}
```

it goes fine across all compilers installed on my system, so if it doesn't compile, either you have non-standard, exoteric settings enabled in your IDE or you are in strong need of a decent compiler.

Comment: That means: immediately rename the parameter to something else.

Comment: When i write it like that: 
void ar(int n,int m, short ar[][]); it compiles as the first bracket and last bracket is an array an the two ][ are like the number that the compiler thought i declared. Then it doesnt work either.Error. An array may not have elements of this type

Comment: Then try `void ar(int n,int m, short **ar)`. If this works, get a more conformant compiler, such as Clang, Intel or GCC.

Comment: I've also tried it b4 posting because i know that i want to use 2 arrays, but it doesn't work, i thought it would but not for me ;S

Comment: **Do rename the third parameter**. What you said above is incorrect: `][` is not a number and you cannot trick the compiler into thinking that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   void ar(int,int,short (*)[]);
```

if it's a declaration and

```
void ar(int m,int n,short (*ar)[]){} // Refer my Edit
```

it it's the definition of the function.

**Edit** Are you really using the same name for the function and the 2D array which you are trying to pass as an argument to the function?

Comment: The thing i would like to produce is :void ar(int n,int m, short (*ar)[])
{
 int r;
 int c;
 for( r = 0; r < n; r++ )
  for( c = 0; c < m; c++ )
   total += (*ar)[r][c]

} But, that doesnt work because i want to have [][] which doesnt work and I've tried it b4, maybe u know?

Answer (score 0):

**VC (C89) can't write like your code.**

for VC like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ar(int n,int m, short *a){
    int i,j, total=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        for(j=0;j<m;++j)
            total += a[i*m+j];
    printf("total=%d\n", total);
}
int main(void){
    short a[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    ar(2, 3, a);// a -> &a[0][0]
    return 0;
}
```